# How to make a command line argument for a calculator

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to create a command line argument for a calculator, any help? Here's my code so far. The question that I'm asked to do is in the block comments in the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class M93 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

/* A simple calculator program is expecting command line arguments that have the form <operand1> <operator> <operand> where both <operand1> and <operand2> 
are integers while <operator> is one of +, -, *, /, or %. Write a method that will calculate and return the value of <operand1> <operator> <operand2>. 
For example, if the command line arguments are 5 + 3, the method should return the value 8. Assume that the command line argument values are all valid.
*/
String s = new String[5];
operator[0] = "+";
operator[1] = "-";
operator[2] = "*";
operator[3] = "/";
operator[4] = "%";
String inputOperator;
int a, b;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
System.out.println("Calculator: " + scanner.nextInt() );

}

public static int addition(int a, int b, int answer) {

answer = (a + b);
System.out.println(answer);
return answer;

}

}
```

Comment: Well, if you're using the command line arguments, you won't need the `Scanner` you have there.

Comment: Do you mean typing in the command >Calculator: 2 + 2 and getting a result?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use `Scanner`.

Run your program like :

> java ClassName 2 3 +

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int frstOperand  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int secndOperand  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String operator = args[2];
        System.out.println("Result :" + doOpearation(frstOperand,secndOperand,operator));
    }

    static int doOpearation(int i,int j, String op) {
        switch (op) {
        case "+":
            return i+j;

        case "-":
            return i-j;

        case "*":
            return i*j;

        case "/":
            return i/j;

        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid opearator");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```